# How can we share code between two TypeScript projects in the same repo?

Tags: typescript, create-react-app

We have a project structure like this:

```
api (dir)

-- package.json

-- tsconfig.json

-- src (dir)

-- client (dir)

---- package.json

---- tsconfig.json

---- src (dir)
```

The "client" dir is a create-react-app project that proxies to the API when developing locally, hence this directory structure.

We'd like to share certain code (constants, utilities) between the two projects.  We've explored a number of ways to do this in TS (e.g. multiple rootdirs) without success.

How specifically can we set up code sharing between these two projects?

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I'd structure it:

```
api
|- src
|- package.json
|- tsconfig.json
client
|- src
|- package.json
|- tsconfig.json
shared
|- src
   |- (shared code goes here)
|- package.json
|- tsconfig.json
package.json
tsconfig.base.json (includes tsconfig options shared between all projects, e.g. strict mode)
```

Then you can set up [yarn workspaces](https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/workspaces#search) in the project, so both of the projects can declare a dependency on `shared`, and yarn will gracefully (as much as it can) orchestrate the dependency resolution of all three.

Note that you'll need to compile the code you have in `shared` in order for the other projects to import it properly.

Comment: can Yarn be used together with npm?

Comment: You technically _can_, but it's better practice to be consistent and use one or the other